# Functional Analysis, $L^p$ spaces

Tags: real-analysis, lp-spaces

Can anyone help me finding for which $p$ the function $$f(x)=\frac{1}{x^{\alpha}+x^{\beta}}  \in L^{p}(0,\infty)$$ where $0<\alpha \le \beta<\infty$ are given.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint 1**

I believe $$f \in L^p(0,\infty) \Leftrightarrow \int_0^\infty |f(x)|^p dx < \infty.$$

So you need to find such a $p$ that
$$
\int_0^\infty \frac{dx}{\left( x^\alpha + x^\beta \right)^p} < \infty.
$$

How would you proceed to do that? Can you get an idea about how to evaluate that integral?

**Hint 2**
A possibly useful transformation is
$$
\int_0^\infty \frac{dx}{\left( x^\alpha + x^\beta \right)^p}
= \int_0^\infty \frac{x^{-\alpha p}dx}{\left( 1 + x^{\beta-\alpha} \right)^p},
$$
and you are given that $\beta - \alpha \ge 0$.

Comment: Thanks for both hints. However, the problem remains in how to evaluate the integral. I tried several transformations including the one you suggested in Hint 2 but I wasn't able to compute such an integral.

Comment: @ChaoukiBenSaid You don't need to *compute* the integral, just prove that it converges. I would try the substituion $u=x^{1-\alpha p}$ which should transform this to a more familiar $\int \left(1+u^c\right)^{-p} du$, where $c = \frac{\beta-\alpha}{1-\alpha p}$ (plus you have to analyze the case $\alpha p = 1$ separately.